# UTL_FILE WITH %ROWTYPE .. ERROR

Tags: utl-file, rowtype

I want to create procedure  that  get rows from employees record whose salary more then input number.
And then get that output to text file. 
I don’t understand where i am doing wrong. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

I have employees table as structured below.
Desc TABLE employees ; 
 Name                                      Null?    Type

---

EMPLOYEE_ID                               NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
 FIRST_NAME                                         VARCHAR2(20)
 LAST_NAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)
 EMAIL                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)
 PHONE_NUMBER                                       VARCHAR2(20)
 HIRE_DATE                                 NOT NULL DATE
 JOB_ID                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 SALARY                                             NUMBER(8,2)
 COMMISSION_PCT                                     NUMBER(2,2)
 MANAGER_ID                                         NUMBER(6)
 DEPARTMENT_ID                                      NUMBER(4)

and when I want to run below script.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_TEST3 ( P_SAL NUMBER) IS

    TYPE EMP_TEMP IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE;
   V_EMP_ROW     EMP_TEMP ;


 V1 utl_file.file_type;

 E1 utl_file.file_type;

    BEGIN


 V1 := utl_file.fopen('ABC','VALID.txt','W');
E1 := utl_file.fopen('ABC','ERROR.txt','W');

SELECT *  BULK COLLECT INTO V_EMP_ROW   FROM Employees  WHERE salary > p_sal   ;

FOR i IN  V_EMP_ROW.FIRST .. V_EMP_ROW.LAST 
    LOOP
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (V1, V_EMP_ROW(I).EMPLOYEE_ID ||',' || V_EMP_ROW(I).FIRST_NAME ||','|| V_EMP_ROW(I).SALARY );
    END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line ('Total row inserted '||sql%rowcount || '.  Please see valid.txt file ' );


EXCEPTION

WHEN OTHERS THEN
raise_application_error( -20002,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);

utl_file.put_line (E1,SQLCODE || '---' || SQLERRM);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('PLEASE SEE Error.txt FILE');

utl_file.fclose(v1);
utl_file.fclose(E1);

 END P_TEST3;
```

/

And the compiler give below error.
[Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
21/42   PLS-00302: component 'EMPLOYEE_ID' must be declared
21/9    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
 (1: 0): Warning: compiled but with compilation errors

Answer (score 0):

The line giving you the error is 21, which appears to be:

```
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (V1, V_EMP_ROW(I).EMPLOYEE_ID ||',' || V_EMP_ROW(I).FIRST_NAME ||','|| V_EMP_ROW(I).SALARY );
```

I would suggest that the issue is that either no rows are being returned in your BULK SELECT statement, or they aren't in the format you expect.

Try putting in something like:

```
dbms_output.put_line('Record is: '|| V_EMPROW(i));
```

as the first line in your loop.

Or, maybe do a record count of the bulk select results prior to the loop:

```
dbms_output.put_line('Record count is: '|| V_EMPROW.COUNT);
```